# Cactus / succulent has holes at the base

Tags: succulents, cactus

I was changing the pot that I noticed the part that was in dirt has holes, it is not wet or soft although I was overwatering it that’s why I wanted to change the soil
I also think it doesn’t have enough roots, do I cut the parts that have holes? And do I put it in water to grow more roots or just leave it?[image]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like rot.

Cactus producing long stems can be easily propagated from stem cutting while bulb-like structure can be easily propagated from pups. From the  picture you provided, it looks like it is a long-stem cactus.

Cut off the damaged parts. You don't need any yellow or yellowish part(I hope you have sufficient stem). Leave the main parts (which you are going to replant) in open air to dry for 3/4 days. **DO NOT** keep them under sun. This is time when callus formation happens. When the cut-end parts look dry, plant them in **well draining sandy soil**. Do not water immediately. Allow it to sit like that for another 3/4 days to a week. After a week, water cautiously. Always let the soil dry out completely before watering again.

I hope you will get back your plant. All the best.

Comment: Rot it is! It looks just like my barrel cactus that rotted out last year.